# Como gerar um arquivo json com as novas noticias para exibir no meu site?

Tags: php, javascript, json

Gostaria de gerar um arquivo JSON para o meu site exibir as últimas noticias no topo para outro site terceiro!

Comment: Seja mais detalhista, por favor, não entendi o que você quer?

Comment: @Rodrido, assim ficou muito amplo. Gerar um  arquivo JSON a partir de um select? a partir de uma chamada de webservice? tente especificar um pouco mais o seu problema, para avitar que sua pergunta seja fechada como muito ampla

Comment: O que são "novas notícias", já tens a query SQL? O que é "no topo"? Porque usou a tag JavaScript? Por favor, confira o guia [ask] e **[edit]e** a pergunta para acrescentar detalhes. Se quiser mais esclarecimentos na resposta já dada, acrescente os detalhes e deixe um comentário na resposta "esclareci tal coisa, confira o update".

Answer (score 7):

Se o site não for do mesmo domínio será necessário usar este código no topo do arquivo.

*PHP*

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); //Qualquer site
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://site.com'); //Especificar os sites
```

Para retornar em `Json` ficaria dessa forma

*PHP*

```
echo json_encode("teste");
```

*Resultado*

> {"teste"}

Para gerar um arquivo

*PHP*

```
$string = "minha string";
$fp = fopen('arquivo.json', 'w');
fwrite($fp, json_encode($string));
fclose($fp);
```

Para suas notícias você deve trazer suas notícias e estruturar em um array e posteriormente imprimir utilizando `json_encode`

Exemplo fictício de um array com as notícias:

PHP

```
$noticias = array(
array(
    "titulo" => "noticia 1",
    "corpo" => "corpo da noticia 1",
    "data" => "02/07/2014"
    ),

array(
    "titulo" => "noticia 2",
    "corpo" => "corpo da noticia 2",
    "data" => "02/07/2014"
),

array(
    "titulo" => "noticia 3",
    "corpo" => "corpo da noticia 3",
    "data" => "02/07/2014"
),

array(
    "titulo" => "noticia 4",
    "corpo" => "corpo da noticia 4",
    "data" => "02/07/2014"
)
);

echo json_encode($noticias);
```

*Resultado*

> [{"titulo":"noticia 1","corpo":"corpo da noticia 1","data":"02/07/2014"},{"titulo":"noticia 2","corpo":"corpo da noticia 2","data":"02/07/2014"},{"titulo":"noticia 3","corpo":"corpo da noticia 3","data":"02/07/2014"},{"titulo":"noticia 4","corpo":"corpo da noticia 4","data":"02/07/2014"}]

E o tratamento desse `Json` pode ser feito com Jquery

*Jquery*

```
$(function(){
    var jsonString = [{"titulo":"noticia 1","corpo":"corpo da noticia 1","data":"02\/07\/2014"},{"titulo":"noticia 2","corpo":"corpo da noticia 2","data":"02\/07\/2014"},{"titulo":"noticia 3","corpo":"corpo da noticia 3","data":"02\/07\/2014"},{"titulo":"noticia 4","corpo":"corpo da noticia 4","data":"02\/07\/2014"}];

    $.each(jsonString, function(i, item){
        $('.noticias').append("<li>"+ item.data +" - " +item.titulo + "</li>");
    });
});
```

Obviamente esse json seria recuperado com um `$.get` ou `$.post` e será tratado no local que deve ficar no site.

[**DEMO - Jquery**](http://jsfiddle.net/dieegov/Hxqq9/)